# Sending an array to server side using $.getJSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using `$.getJSON()` to pass some data to the server side (PHP, Codeigniter) and using the return data to do some work. The data that I am sending over to the server is in the form of an array.

**Problem:** When an associative array is sent to the server, no result is received on server side. However, if a normal array with numerical indexes is sent, the data is received on server side. How can I send an array of data over to the server?

**JS Code (Not Working)**

```
boundary_encoded[0]['testA'] = 'test';
boundary_encoded[0]['testB'] = 'test1';

$.getJSON('./boundary_encoded_insert_into_db_ajax.php',
    {boundary_encoded: boundary_encoded},
    function(json) {

        console.log(json);

});
```

**JS Code (Works)**

```
boundary_encoded[0][0] = 'test0';
boundary_encoded[0][1] = 'test1';

$.getJSON('./boundary_encoded_insert_into_db_ajax.php',
    {boundary_encoded: boundary_encoded},
    function(json) {

        console.log(json);

});
```

**PHP Code**

```
$boundary_encoded = $_GET['boundary_encoded'];
print_r($_GET);
```

**Error Msg**

```
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: boundary_encoded in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\boundary\boundary_encoded_insert_into_db_ajax.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
Array
(
)
```

**Working Result**

```
Array
(
    [boundary_encoded] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test
                    [1] => test1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: This should be working in both cases. Are you sure there's no typo or other mistake?

Comment: I copy pasted the code that I'm actually running... I wonder why its not working!

Comment: Is `boundary_encoded[0]` an array or an object? If its an array, you can't do `boundary_encoded[0]['testA']` as JavaScript doesn't do associative arrays. Instead it will add a `.testA` property to the array but it won't be enumerable, which is why nothhing gets sent to the server.

Comment: It is an associative array! How can this array be turned into an object so it can be passed to server side with the associative key intact? Or is there a better way to pass the associative array over?

Comment: There is no such thing as an associative array in JavaScript. You either have indexed arrays e.g. `[1,2,3]` or object literals e.g. `{'testA':'foo'}`.

Comment: How should I create an object literal of the form `boundary_encoded[0]['testA'] = 'test'` in a loop, where the first index is a running counter? I figure the object literal will be something like `{ '1': {'testA' : 'test'}, '2': {'testB' : 'test1} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because JavaScript does not support associative arrays. This assignment:

`boundary_encoded[0]['testA'] = 'test';`

*appears* to work in JS because you can assign a new property to any object, arrays included. However they won't be enumerated in a `for` loop.

Instead, you must use an object literal:

`boundary_encoded[0] = {'testA':'test'};`

You can then use `JSON.stringify` to convert `boundary_encoded` to a JSON string, send that to the server, and use PHP's `json_decode()` function to convert the string back into an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using converting the arrays to JSON.  If you can't do so in PHP (using the json_encode function), here are a couple of JS equivalents:

- http://phpjs.org/functions/json_encode:457
- http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php

Comment: I am trying to send the array from clientside Javascript to serverside PHP. I suppose I need to send it using object literal instead of associative arrays which does not exist in Javascript

Comment: I wasn't sure how much of your code depended on the use of arrays, but yes... it would be a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In your getJSON call, use

```
{boundary_encoded: JSON.stringify(boundary_encoded)},
```

instead of

```
{boundary_encoded: boundary_encoded},
```